# To have your blinkers on

Tags: idioms

On the eve of England India World Cup cricket match on 30.6.2019, Jos Buttler said

> "The mood in the camp is still very good. Naturally there is some external pressure and it would be naive to say we have got our blinkers on."

Is it good or bad to have your blinkers on?

Comment: I'm in the US.  "To have your blinkers on" to me means: lights blinking on your car when it is in a dangerous situation, so that others will notice you. But I suppose if Jos Buttler is English he probably meant "blinkers" as what we call "blinders" in the U.S.  (see James' answer).

Answer (score 2):

It’s bad.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkers_(horse_tack))

> Blinkers, sometimes known as blinders, are a piece of horse tack that prevent the horse seeing to the rear and, in some cases, to the side.

Having a view of everything is better.

Comment: 'Horse tack'? I think you mean 'tackle'.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy - A "tack shop" is a shop that sells stuff that horses "wear".  A "tackle shop" is a place that sells fishing gear.

Comment: "Blinders" is not universally negative -- depends on context.  Sometimes (eg, while working on a computer in an environment with flashing lights) people will intentionally don blinders to prevent distractions.

Comment: @HotLicks: sorry, I really used a bad dictionary to look it up. :(